# How can I calculate the course angle of two coordinates in decimal degrees?

Tags: javascript, latitude-longitude, angles, geodesy, geodesic

I want to calculate course angle of two given decimal degrees, like shown in the following picture:
[image]
In the above picture the result would be 135°

The coordinates are given in decimal degrees, e.g. (lon, lat) :

```
var A = [11.133073, 47.149368]
var B = [11.094844, 47.13155]
```

If possible, in JavaScript.

Comment: Get a geodetic library to do it for you. Search on "Inverse Geodetic Problem" (aka "Reverse Geodetic Problem")

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use the Inverse-function of the following website: https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/js/module-GeographicLib_Geodesic.Geodesic.html. Do you know what the difference between az1 and az2 is and which I have to use?

Comment: Have a look at docs at https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/js/tutorial-2-interface.html. Use the one you need.

Comment: When doing spheroidal math, the inverse of the outward orientation (back angle) isn't the  inverse of the forward angle, so both are given.